# managing local workstation groups remotely

Tags: c#

I've been trying a few things in C# to accomplish this on a remote workstation:

```
net localgroup administrators "MyAdminGroup1" /add
net localgroup administrators "MyAdminGroup2" /add
net localgroup users "MyUserGroup" /add
net localgroup users "Domain Users" /delete
```

Considered PsExec to execute cmd.exe remotely and use StreamWriter to run the commands in a loop. I'm not getting an error but the function keeps hanging. I've sifted through some resources online and learned I'm encountering issues with asynchronous read/write, buffer filled up, PsExec waiting on cmd.exe indefinitely, etc.

My question is, am I going about this the right way? Using Process() + PsExec + cmd.exe to execute "net localgroup administrators "MyAdminGroup1" /add" on remote workstations or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here's my loop that hangs on StandardOutput.ReadLine():

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> group in listOfLocalUserGroups) {
            string label = group.Key;
            string command = group.Value;
            string psExecArguments = string.Format(@"-u {0}\{1} -p {2} \\{3} cmd.exe", domain, username, password, hostname);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}\n{2}\nPlease wait...", label, command, psExecArguments);
            Process remoteProcess = new Process();
            remoteProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            remoteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            remoteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            remoteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            remoteProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "PsExec.exe";
            remoteProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = psExecArguments;

            try {
                List<string> strOut = new List<string>();
                List<string> strErr = new List<string>();

                remoteProcess.Start();
                StreamWriter remoteCommand = remoteProcess.StandardInput;
                remoteCommand.WriteLine(command);
                remoteCommand.Close();

                while (remoteProcess.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1) {
                    strOut.Add(remoteProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                }
                while (remoteProcess.StandardError.Peek() > -1) {
                    strErr.Add(remoteProcess.StandardError.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("\n## {0} ##", label);

                Console.WriteLine("Output: ");
                foreach (string stringOut in strOut) {
                    Console.WriteLine(stringOut);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: ");
                foreach (string stringErr in strErr) {
                    Console.WriteLine(stringErr);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(SuperReconfig.SECTION);
            }
            catch (Exception err) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to complete {0}", label);
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}\n", err.Message);
            }
            finally {
                Console.ResetColor();
                remoteProcess.Close();
            }
        }
```